# jquery filtering by field "deleted"

Tags: jquery

I have a problem trying to show registries marked as "deleted" in my customers table. I want to select these rows dynamically when I choose the  value from a combo with values "Yes" or "Not" using jquery. Can you help me please?

```
<table id="customer_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">  
<h3>Customer</h3>                           
 <thead>
   <tr>  
      <td class="tiles">ID</td>  
      <td class="titles">NAME</td>  
      <td class="titles">PHONE</td>  
      <td class="titles">DELETED</td>  
      <td class="titles" width="10%"><a width href ="customer_management.php"       class="button_new">New</a></td>
   </tr>  
 </thead>                            

<?php 
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
?>                          
<tr>                                     
  <td width="10%"><?php echo $row ['memo'];?></td>
  <td width="50%"><?php echo $row ['name'];?></td>
  <td width="30%"><?php echo $row ['phone'];?></td>
  <td width="10%">

  <?php if ($row['DELETED']==0){echo 'NO';} else{echo 'YES';}?>
  </td>                                    
  <td width="10%"><a href ="customer_management.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];   ?>&oper=mod" class="button">MODIFY</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}  
?>  

</table> 

<!-- COMBO WITH 2 VALUES, YES OR NOT, TO SELECT THE DELETED CUSTOMERS OR NOT -->

<label for="show_deleted">Show deleted customers:</label>
<select id="show_deleted" name="show_deleted">                        
<?php
    echo "<option SELECTED value='0'>NO" ;
    echo "<option value='1'>YES" ;
?>            
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){      
    $('#customer_data').DataTable();      
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the "Deleted: Yes/No-td to make it easier to select it (e.g. `class="td-deleted`):

```
<td class="td-deleted" width="10%">
  <?php if ($row['DELETED']==0){echo 'NO';} else{echo 'YES';}?>
</td>
```

Then you can use a code like this:

```
$(function() {
  hide_deleted_rows();
  $('#show_deleted').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()=='0'){
      hide_deleted_rows();
    }else{
      $('#customer_data').find('tr').each(function(){
        $(this).show();
      });
    } 
  });
});

function hide_deleted_rows(){
  $('#customer_data').find('tr').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('.td-deleted').html()=="YES"){
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8x7L6exk/)

Comment: It works fine, but I realise that is only hiding registries in my datatable, rows aren't being grouped by this value. e.g. first page with one "not deleted" registry and second page with 15. Is there any possibility to join all rows in first page?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you please describe in more detail or in other words?